# error inserting data into database

Tags: sql

i was trying to insert a record into the database so i created a method insert. the problem is that i keep getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 7
```

here is my code

```
public void InsertDataInDB (Connection conn, Statement stmt, event MyNewEvent,String TableName){

   try {
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();

       //String Values = MyNewEvent.EventName+"', '"+MyNewEvent.Location+"', '"+MyNewEvent.Description+"', '"+MyNewEvent.Creator+"', '"+MyNewEvent.startDate+"', '"+MyNewEvent.endDate;
       //Values = "'sjsjs','sss',''";
       String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TableName+ " (EventName, Location, Description, Creater, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ;
       PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

       statement.setString(1, MyNewEvent.EventName);
       statement.setString(2, MyNewEvent.Location);
       statement.setString(3, MyNewEvent.Description);
       statement.setString(4, MyNewEvent.Creator);
       statement.setString(5, MyNewEvent.startDate);
       statement.setString(6, MyNewEvent.endDate);
       statement.execute();
       System.out.println("Successfully inserted record into database");
   }
   catch(SQLException se){
           se.printStackTrace();

   }//end finally try


}
```

Comment: Try replacing TableName with hardcoded database table name and see what happens.

Comment: try **String sql = "INSERT INTO [" + TableName+ "] ([EventName], [Location], [Description], [Creater], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";**

Answer (score 0):

It was the table name that was wrong in the function call in main. thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: lack of reputation does not give you the right to write a comment as a response!